2022 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #5 on Cryptography has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Also, please join me in thanking SEJPM, who will be stepping down as moderator after serving as a moderator since the 2018 election:

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Neato.${}{}{}{}{}$

Absolutely.....

Comparison of the last three elections by voters;




year
The number of voters
valid votes
empty votes




2022
162
162
0


2020
246
246
0


2018
186
186 (?)
0 (?)



